# Express the given polar equation in simplest rectangular form: $r = 4 + 3cosθ$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Express the given polar equation in simplest rectangular form: $r = 4 + 3cosθ$

**My attempt**

Multiplying r on both sides, we get

$r^2=4r+3 rcos\theta$

since, $x=rcos\theta$ and $y=rsin\theta$
and $r^2=x^2+y^2$

we get $x^2+y^2=4r+3x$

can anyone please explain after this step..

Comment: put $r =\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. and after that simplify if you can. also it should be $3x$ not $3y$

Comment: move the $3x$ to the left side and square

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$r^2 - 4 r = 3 x$$

$$x^2 +y^2 - 4\sqrt{x^2 +y^2} = 3 x$$

which represents a cardoid.. it is *better to leave it that way*.

if you try to get rid of radical sign you end up with another equation representing another symmetrical cardoid,  not  really what you wanted to represent at the outset:

$$x^2 +y^2 + 4\sqrt{x^2 +y^2} = 3 x$$

Comment: So, the final answer is this right $$x^2 +y^2 - 4\sqrt{x^2 +y^2} = 3 x$$

Comment: Yes,right. To confirm, it is better to graph them both.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for $r\neq 0$ we get $$r=4+3\cos(\theta)$$
so you will get
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=4+\frac{3x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Comment: Can you explain after that step

Comment: That fact is given . OP wants to convert that to rectangular form

Comment: so, should I substitute $r=\sqrt { x^ 2+y^ 2 } $

Answer (score 0):

You have $r= 4+3\cos(\theta)$

$r^2 = 4r+3r\cos(\theta)$

we know that ;$x= r\cos(\theta)\qquad y = r\sin(\theta)$

$r^2 = x^2+y^2$

$\implies x^2+y^2 =\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+3x$

$\implies (x^2+y^2-3x)^2 = x^2+y^2$